# create module garage in customer like addresses

Tags: customer, extensions, customer-group, tabs

I need to create a module garage in customer like addresses where I can add new garage.
Could you give me some ideas?
thanks
For the moment, this is what I have
[image]

this is my code bellow

PMC/Garagetab/Block/Adminhtml/Garage/Tab.php

```
<?php
class PMC_Garagetab_Block_Adminhtml_Garage_Tab
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface {
   /**
     * Set the template for the block
     *
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
       $this->setTemplate('garagetab/tab.phtml');
    }
   /**
     * Retrieve the label used for the tab relating to this block
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return $this->__('Mes Garages');
    }
   /**
     * Retrieve the title used by this tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->__('Click here to view your garages tab content');
    }
   /**
     * Determines whether to display the tab
     * Add logic here to decide whether you want the tab to display
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Stops the tab being hidden
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

file config.xml

```
<config>
   <modules>
       <PMC_Garagetab>
           <version>0.1.0</version>
       </PMC_Garagetab>
   </modules>
   <adminhtml>
        <layout>
           <updates>
               <garagetab>
                  <file>garagetab.xml</file>
               </garagetab>
           </updates>
       </layout>
   </adminhtml>  
   <global>
       <blocks>
           <garagetab>
               <class>PMC_Garagetab_Block</class>
           </garagetab>
       </blocks>
 </global>
</config>
```

file design/adminhtml/default/default/template/garagetab/tab.phtml

```
<div id="garage_info_tabs_garage_edit_tab_action_content">
    <div class="entry-edit">
        <div class="entry-edit-head">
            <h4 class="icon-head head-edit-form fieldset-legend">Action Tab</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="group_fields4" class="fieldset fieldset-wide">
            <div class="hor-scroll">
                <table class="form-list" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <td>Garage Custom Action Tab Contents Here</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Take a look at `class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Addresses` in **core** folder. You will need to duplicate something similar for your Garage.

Comment: hi @lloiacono, thanks for your comment. I have already seen this file, it is very long. I need a simple exemple CRUD to save,delete,update my fields in the database

Answer (score 0):

I'm searching for a Magento 2 garage addon too, something where i can store VIN numbers, car details like color, model etc. connected to the client info in magento 2.